# How to calculate longest undefeated streak using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a web page that lists various longest streaks for a single team, but I've encountered an issue when trying to calculate a streak for a combination of result types involved.

The data is presented in a table as follows...

```
date         result   gf   ga   type     compfull
--------------------------------------------------
1980-08-16      W     3    0   league    Division 1
1980-08-19      L     1    2   league    Division 1
1980-08-23      W     3    1   league    Division 1
1980-08-26      W     2    0   league    Division 1
1980-08-30      D     2    2   league    Division 1
and so on...
```

Using the following query (or similar), I can determine the longest run of wins or losses or even games scored in.

```
SELECT result, type, MIN(date) as StartDate, MAX(date) as EndDate, COUNT(*) as Games 
FROM (SELECT result, type, date, compfull, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM resultengine R 
WHERE R.result <> RE.result
AND R.date <= RE.date) as RunGroup
FROM resultengine RE) A WHERE result='W' GROUP BY result, RunGroup ORDER BY Games
```

This is based on the excellent resource I found [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/detecting-runs-or-streaks-in-your-data). It does exactly what I want it to and tells me what I want to know - the same applies if I change to

```
result='L'
```

What I can't work out is how to calculate the longest streak of undefeated games i.e. the longest run without an L. And it's the same vice-versa.

I've tried the following query to no avail:

```
SELECT result, type, MIN(date) as StartDate, MAX(date) as EndDate, COUNT(*) as Games 
FROM (SELECT result, type, date, compfull, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM resultengine R 
WHERE R.result <> RE.result
AND R.date <= RE.date) as RunGroup
FROM resultengine RE) A WHERE result!='W' GROUP BY result, RunGroup ORDER BY Games
```

I've also tried altering the query to:

```
WHERE result='W' OR result='D'
```

Again, this doesn't work. Both attempts mirror the query that's used to deliver the longest streak of Ws or Ls - and a manual count of my data tells me that isn't correct. I'm no doubt missing something simple here, but how can I execute that query so it tells me the longest streak of results with either Ls or Ws?

Comment: Which column/columns you use to identify "a single team" ?

Comment: @seahawk The whole table is a collection of one team's results - the column "gf" contains the goals scored by this team, whereas "ga" are goals conceded. I do have an "opponent" column that's not shown as it's not relevant (I believe) to this query. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Please check my answer and confirm whether its working for you.

Comment: I missed MAX function. I regret for that. I have updated the code. Please check it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extended from your code sample the following gives runs of wins/draws. The problem was with 'WHERE R.result <> RE.result' which always assigned different groupings for any different result code. Here I change that clause (and some others) to group 'W' and 'D' together to make a single code:

```
SELECT result, TYPE, MIN(DATE) AS StartDate, MAX(DATE) AS EndDate, COUNT(*) AS Games 
FROM (SELECT result, TYPE, DATE, compfull, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM resultengine R 
  WHERE IF(R.result IN ('W','D'),1,0) <> IF(RE.result IN ('W','D'),1,0)
  AND R.date <= RE.date) AS RunGroup
FROM resultengine RE) A WHERE result IN ('W','D') GROUP BY IF(result IN ('W','D'),1,0), RunGroup ORDER BY Games
```

Comment: Thanks @Giles - that works great for calculating the overall runs. If I had an extra column called "Venue" to identify "H" or "A" games, can the query be refined further to work out the longest string of H games or A games too?

Comment: I believe so, from what you say I imagine you would need to replace `result` with `venue` and IN ('W','D') with = 'H', = 'A') or IN ('H','A') for both.

Comment: Apologies @Giles, I perhaps wasn't clear there - I meant calculating the longest string of Ws or Ds (or both) where venue = H or A. 

Would it be a case, therefore, of adding `venue = H` to the query as an extra `where` clause?

Comment: Yes, I think so, you would need the clause in the RunGroup sub select though.

Comment: This is the query I've used @Giles, though the runs it returns aren't entirely accurate - have I misunderstood what you meant?

`SELECT result, TYPE, MIN(DATE) AS StartDate, MAX(DATE) AS EndDate, COUNT(*) AS Games 
FROM (SELECT result, venue, TYPE, DATE, compfull, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM resultengine R 
  WHERE IF(R.result IN ('W','D'),1,0) <> IF(RE.result IN ('W','D'),1,0)
  AND(R.venue = 'H') <> (RE.venue = 'H')
  AND R.date <= RE.date) AS RunGroup
FROM resultengine RE) A WHERE venue = 'H' AND result IN ('W','D') GROUP BY IF(result IN ('W','D'),1,0), RunGroup ORDER BY Games`

Comment: Possibly Try replacing AND(R.venue = 'H') <> (RE.venue = 'H') with AND(R.venue in ( 'H','A')) AND (RE.venue IN ('H','A')).

Comment: Sadly this hasn't worked either @Giles - the runs being returned are still coming up shorter than what they should to be (having done a manual count)

Comment: Sorry, you will just have to keep experimenting. The trick here is to build the groupings you want. Identify the group you want to count, build code that gives one code for in the group and another for out of group (like I did with `IF(R.result IN ('W','D'),1,0))` and integrate this into your code block. I cannot keep writing code for you, you`re not paying me enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you max undefeated sequence for a single team (the table contains data for single team:

```
select MAX(final.win_seq_count) from

(Select date,result,gf,ga,type,compfull,
 @seq_count:=if(result="L",0,@seq_count:=@seq_count+1) as win_seq_count,
from resultengine,(select @seq_count:=0) t


order by date) final
```

Note: Code may contain small syntactic error.