# How to calculate longest streak using MySQL and two 'where' clauses

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a follow-up to my initial question on how to [calculate the longest undefeated streak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206242/how-to-calculate-longest-undefeated-streak-using-mysql).

I've amended my data table to add a "venue" column to show if a game was "home" or "away":

```
date         result   venue
-----------------------------
1980-08-16      W     H
1980-08-19      L     A
1980-08-23      W     A
1980-08-26      W     H
1980-08-30      D     H
and so on...
```

I have been successful in calculating the longest overall streaks thanks to my previous question, but now I'd like to calculate those streaks by venue and I'm not sure how to go about it.

For the most home consecutive home wins, for example, I have tried the following query - but the resulting 'runs' are being returned shorter than they actually are (based on a manual count of the data) and there's no obvious interruption:

SQL:

```
SELECT
    result,
    venue,
    MIN(date) as StartDate,
    MAX(date) as EndDate,
    COUNT(*) as Games 
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            result,
            venue,
            date, 
            (
                SELECT
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    resultengine R 
                WHERE
                    R.result <> RE.result
                    AND
                    (R.venue = 'H') <> (RE.venue = 'H')
                    AND
                    R.date <= RE.date
            ) as RunGroup
        FROM
            resultengine RE
    ) A 
WHERE
    venue = 'H'
    AND
    result='W' 
GROUP BY
    result, RunGroup 
ORDER BY
    Games
```

PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query( /* the SQL statement from above */ );


while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
{
    $startrundate = date("d F Y",strtotime($row['StartDate'])); 
    $endrundate = date("d F Y",strtotime($row['EndDate'])); 
    echo "<tr>";   
    echo "<td>".$row['Games']."</td>";
    echo "<td class='tableprofile' style='text-align:right;'>".$startrundate." - ".$endrundate."</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";    
    $rowCount += 1;
}
```

It is proving more difficult than I had imagined, but similarly don't believe I'm too far away from the solution. It's just bridging that gap between what I have and what I'm not currently doing.

**UPDATE**

I seem to have resolved this particular issue. And it was as simple as changing the clause `(R.venue = 'H') <> (RE.venue = 'H')` to `R.venue = RE.venue`

Comment: Also you are selecting venue but not performing an aggregate op or including it in your groupby - this is going to cause a lot of problems - this is again a mysql issue from not adhering to SQL standards.

Comment: How are gf ,  ga,   type , and compfull relevant to this problem?

Comment: For the purposes of this particular question @Strawberry, they are not relevant - I shall edit them out.

Comment: I see you resolved your post in update. You know you can [answer and accept your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Please do so for future readers to know question is resolved. Also please add venue to `GROUP BY` clause to be ANSI-SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following ignores any SQL and assumes you just have a list of "games" and you want to work out the longest streak. In this case I've assumed a "game" is a class with a method `wasWon()`.

```
$currentStreak = 0;
$longestString = 0;

foreach($games as $game) {
    if(!$game->wasWon()) {
        $currentStreak = 0;
        continue;
    }
    $currentStreak++;
    if($currentStreak > $longestStreak) {
        $longestStreak = $currentStreak;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to expand the logic to only care about home games, you could wrap the whole logic:

```
foreach($games as $game) {
    if($game->wasHomeGame()) {
        if(!$game->wasWon()) {
            $currentStreak = 0;
            continue;
        }
        $currentStreak++;
        if($currentStreak > $longestStreak) {
            $longestStreak = $currentStreak;
        }
    }
}
```

This would be better placed in a class with more flexibility, for example you could use a value class to say where the came was played:

```
public function getLongestStreak(array $games, Venue $venue) {
    $currentStreak = 0;
    $longestString = 0;
    foreach($games as $game) {
        if($game instanceof Game && $game->wasPlayedAt($venue)) {
            if(!$game->wasWon()) {
                $currentStreak = 0;
                continue;
            }
            $currentStreak++;
            if($currentStreak > $longestStreak) {
                $longestStreak = $currentStreak;
            }
        }
    }
    return $longestStreak;
}
```

I could go on to describe how the Value Classes might work here, but I'm just distracting myself from work, and hopefully I've solved your issue. ;)

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated for a long time with good reason and are removed in PHP 7. I recommend using an ORM such as Doctrine, but if you prefer DIY, look at PDO. You can load your results directly into value classes which could provide the functionality described above.